# error:can't set header after they are send while referencing collections node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, collections

I have two collection assign and final. My code is like this

```
app.post('/checkuser',function(req,res){

        //var id="ObjectId('"+req.body.id+"')";
        var mongo=require('mongodb');
    var ObjectID=require('mongodb').ObjectID;
    var obj_id=new ObjectID(req.body.id);

        //var username=req.body.username;
        mongoClient.connect(url,function(err,db){
            db.collection('assign',function(err,collection){
                collection.findOne({"_id":obj_id},function(err,result){
                    res.send(result);   
                    db.final.findOne({"username":result.user.username},function(err,results){
                        res.send(results);
                    })
                })
                })
            })
    })
```

The data in the assign collection is in this format

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59674fb5a13752326c939dcd"),
        "user" : {
                "username" : "c",
                "password" : "v"
        }
}
```

and the data in final collection is like this

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59674cfc081305f9c8b5bc58"),
        "username" : "c",
        "name" : "MAC",
        "asset" : "PRO",
        "place" : "Bangalore"
}
```

I want to access the data for the username:"c" by providing the id in assign collection.
With the above code, I get error - Can't set header after they are sent.
What is the correct way of implementing this?

Comment: you need to manipulate result data in an object, and send it, in the end of the request.

Comment: How is that done? @AnkitBalyan

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `res.send()` multiple times for the same `res`. You can only send a response once for a single HTTP request.

If you want to respond with multiple pieces of information, you will need to combine them in some way before passing it to `res.send()`.

Comment: how can that be done. Do I need to make nested ajax calls?

Comment: Try just deleting the first res.send() call `res.send(result);`. That might even do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the error basically means that the data is already sent and then the header is getting manipulated.Also, res object cannot be called multiple times in the same function. So, the second query should be executed in the success function of the first function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
 mongoClient.connect(url,function(err,db){
        db.collection('assign',function(err,collection){
            collection.findOne({"_id":obj_id},function(err,result){
                db.final.findOne({"username":result.user.username},function(err, result, results){
                    res.send({ "first": result, "second": results });
                })
            })
            })
        })
```

Sorry, I can't verify that, but what it is aiming to do is pass the first result into the next function and then send an object with both results in it. If it works, it should at least get you moving again.

You are into a chaotic territory because you are nesting fairly deep. I recommend learning about and practicing Promises and async/await. Aim to make a function for each thing, and each function should have only one purpose. You should also research "callback hell", what it is and how to avoid it.